# Twilio API Error

Tags: swift

I am making a chat app in swift and I got the source code of the Twilio webpage. I  keep getting these unresolved Identifier errors in my Viewcontroller code. Do I have to import the Json code or do I have to import my bridging header.

Here is my View Controller Code.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController {

// MARK: IP messaging memebers
var client: TwilioIPMessagingClient? = nil
var generalChannel: TWMChannel? = nil
var identity = ""
var messages: [TWMMessage] = []

// MARK: UI controls
@IBOutlet weak var bottomConstraint: NSLayoutConstraint!
@IBOutlet weak var textField: UITextField!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    // Fetch Access Token form the server and initialize IPM Client - this assumes you are running
    // the PHP starter app on your local machine, as instructed in the quick start guide
    let deviceId = UIDevice.currentDevice().identifierForVendor!.UUIDString
    let urlString = "http://localhost:8000/token.php?device=\(deviceId)"
    let defaultChannel = "general"

    // Get JSON from server
    let config = NSURLSessionConfiguration.defaultSessionConfiguration()
    let session = NSURLSession(configuration: config, delegate: nil, delegateQueue: nil)
    let url = NSURL(string: urlString)
    let request  = NSMutableURLRequest(URL: url!)
    request.HTTPMethod = "GET"

    // Make HTTP request
    session.dataTaskWithRequest(request, completionHandler: { data, response, error in
        if (data != nil) {
            // Parse result JSON
            let json = JSON(data: data!)
            let token = json["token"].stringValue
            self.identity = json["identity"].stringValue

            // Set up Twilio IPM client and join the general channel
            self.client = TwilioIPMessagingClient.ipMessagingClientWithToken(token, delegate: self)

            // Auto-join the general channel
            self.client?.channelsListWithCompletion { result, channels in
                if (result == .Success) {
                    if let channel = channels.channelWithUniqueName(defaultChannel) {
                        // Join the general channel if it already exists
                        self.generalChannel = channel
                        self.generalChannel?.joinWithCompletion({ result in
                            print("Channel joined with result \(result)")
                        })
                    } else {
                        // Create the general channel (for public use) if it hasn't been created yet
                        channels.createChannelWithFriendlyName("General Chat Channel", type: .Public) {
                            (channelResult, channel) -> Void in
                            if result == .Success {
                                self.generalChannel = channel
                                self.generalChannel?.joinWithCompletion({ result in
                                    self.generalChannel?.setUniqueName(defaultChannel, completion: { result in
                                        print("channel unqiue name set")
                                    })
                                })
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

            // Update UI on main thread
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
                self.navigationItem.prompt = "Logged in as \"\(self.identity)\""
            }
        } else {
            print("Error fetching token :\(error)")
        }
    }).resume()

    // Listen for keyboard events and animate text field as necessary
    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: Selector("keyboardWillShow:"),
        name:UIKeyboardWillShowNotification,
        object: nil);

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: Selector("keyboardDidShow:"),
        name:UIKeyboardDidShowNotification,
        object: nil);

    NSNotificationCenter.defaultCenter().addObserver(self,
        selector: Selector("keyboardWillHide:"),
        name:UIKeyboardWillHideNotification,
        object: nil);

    // Set up UI controls
    self.tableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
    self.tableView.estimatedRowHeight = 66.0
    self.tableView.separatorStyle = .None
}

// MARK: Keyboard Dodging Logic

func keyboardWillShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    let keyboardHeight = notification.userInfo?[UIKeyboardFrameBeginUserInfoKey]?.CGRectValue.height
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = keyboardHeight! + 10
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}

func keyboardDidShow(notification: NSNotification) {
    self.scrollToBottomMessage()
}

func keyboardWillHide(notification: NSNotification) {
    UIView.animateWithDuration(0.1, animations: { () -> Void in
        self.bottomConstraint.constant = 20
        self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
    })
}

// MARK: UI Logic

// Dismiss keyboard if container view is tapped
@IBAction func viewTapped(sender: AnyObject) {
    self.textField.resignFirstResponder()
}

// Scroll to bottom of table view for messages
func scrollToBottomMessage() {
    if self.messages.count == 0 {
        return
    }
    let bottomMessageIndex = NSIndexPath(forRow: self.tableView.numberOfRowsInSection(0) - 1,
        inSection: 0)
    self.tableView.scrollToRowAtIndexPath(bottomMessageIndex, atScrollPosition: .Bottom,
        animated: true)
}

}

// MARK: Twilio IP Messaging Delegate
extension ViewController: TwilioIPMessagingClientDelegate {
// Called whenever a channel we've joined receives a new message
func ipMessagingClient(client: TwilioIPMessagingClient!, channel: TWMChannel!,
    messageAdded message: TWMMessage!) {
        self.messages.append(message)
        self.tableView.reloadData()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) {
            if self.messages.count > 0 {
                self.scrollToBottomMessage()
            }
        }
}
}

// MARK: UITextField Delegate
extension ViewController: UITextFieldDelegate {
func textFieldShouldReturn(textField: UITextField) -> Bool {
    let msg = self.generalChannel?.messages.createMessageWithBody(textField.text!)
    self.generalChannel?.messages.sendMessage(msg) { result in
        textField.text = ""
        textField.resignFirstResponder()
    }
    return true
}
}

// MARK: UITableView Delegate
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

// Return number of rows in the table
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    return self.messages.count
}

// Create table view rows
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
    -> UITableViewCell {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("MessageCell", forIndexPath: indexPath)
        let message = self.messages[indexPath.row]

        // Set table cell values
        cell.detailTextLabel?.text = message.author
        cell.textLabel?.text = message.body
        cell.selectionStyle = .None
        return cell
}
}

// MARK: UITableViewDataSource Delegate
extension ViewController: UITableViewDataSource {
func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int {
    return 1
}
}
```

The lines of code with errors are,

```
var client: TwilioIPMessagingClient? = nil
var generalChannel: TWMChannel? = nil

var messages: [TWMMessage] = []

self.client = TwilioIPMessagingClient.ipMessagingClientWithToken(token, delegate: self)


extension ViewController: TwilioIPMessagingClientDelegate {
// Called whenever a channel we've joined receives a new message
func ipMessagingClient(client: TwilioIPMessagingClient!, channel: TWMChannel!,
    messageAdded message: TWMMessage!)
```

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like you have to add a Twilio framework to your project.

Comment: Do You know what that Framework is Called. @ryantxr

Comment: I do not know. Twilio should tell you if they provided the code.

Comment: Nothing comes up in Xcode frameworks for Twilio. @ryantxr

Answer (score 0):

The following is from the project on GitHub:

Note: The current version of the app uses a fixed version of Twilio SDK (included in the repository). This version only work for arm devices as the SDK includes some native code.

https://github.com/TwilioDevEd/twiliochat-swift/tree/master